# Custom CSS won't override bootstrap

Tags: html, css

Let me proceed by saying that I have searched Google and Stack Overflow to find the answer to this. I have tried many solutions, but none are working.

The main issue right now is the fact that my CSS won't override the Bootstrap CSS in the jumbotron. It won't change the background color, background image or nav bar settings.

I have tried using `!important`. I have tried calling my stylesheet after calling the bootstrap one. In my current version, I have the `@import` code to call the Bootstrap CSS at the beginning of my own CSS file. None have worked. For a few items, I changed the bootstrap file, but only for color.

Please help me figure out why my file will not override bootstrap. You can see the site at http://www.dismantledesign.com/testsite2/

The site is incomplete. I just can't proceed with styling until I figure this out.

Sorry if any code ends up missing. SO doesn't always like my pastes from TextWrangler. Feel free to look at it via the source code in the link.

Code below:

```
    @import url("bootstrap.min.css");

    body{
    font-family: 'Raleway', Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #666666;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    }

    p{
    line-height: 20pt;
    font-weight: 400;
    }

    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
    color: #333333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Raleway', Helvetica, Arial;
    font-weight: 700;
    }

    a{
    color: #00acec;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Raleway', Helvetica, Arial;
    font-weight: 600;
    }

    a:hover, a:focus{
    color: #5a5e61;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

   .btn-default{
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #a7adb0;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #a7adb0;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 11px 20px;
    }

  .btn-default:hover{
   background: #5a5e61;
   color: #a7adb0;
   }

   /*end*/

  /*logo*/

 .navbar-brand{
  width: 174px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;

  }

  /*end*/

 /*navigation*/

 .navbar-default{
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 0 60px 0;
 }

 .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #a7adb0;
  padding: 11px 0;
  text-align: center;
  }

 .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover[
  color: #fff;
  }

 .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover{
  background: none;
  outline: 0;
  color: #fff;
  } 


.navbar-toggle{
 border: none;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 width:32px;
 height: 32px;
 text-align: center;
 }

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse{
border: none;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) !important;
border-radius: 2px;
box-shadow: none;
}

.jumbotron{
background: #363737 url("img/tempjumbotron.jpg") no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
max-height: 800px;
padding: 60px 0;
margin: 0;
}

/*end*/
```

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">




    <head>

<!--Hey, this is the CC title!-->
<title>Contra Coda Media | Audio | Photo | Video</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

<!--This is where the CSS comes from. -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display-->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only"> Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo5.png"></a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect Nav Content -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--END NAVBAR COLLAPSE-->
        </nav>

        <div class="row text-center">
            <h1>THIS IS CONTRA CODA</h1>
            <h3>where the music never ends</h3>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">LEARN MORE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--END JUMBOTRON-->

<div class="whatsnew">

    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/levelup.jpg" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/heartwhole.jpg" alt="">
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!--END WHATS NEW-->

<div class="services">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="services-audio text-center">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <span style="font-size: 30px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones">&nbsp;</span>
                    <h4>AUDIO</h4>
                    <p>We believe in good, thoroughly crafted recording and mixing with great care in order to achieve a high-quality result.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="more">learn more</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="services-photo text-center">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <span style="font-size: 30px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera">&nbsp;</span>
                    <h4>PHOTO</h4>
                    <p>We believe in good, thoroughly crafted recording with great care in order to achieve a high-quality result.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="more">learn more</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="services-video text-center">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <span style="font-size: 30px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video">&nbsp;</span>
                    <h4>VIDEO</h4>
                    <p>We believe in good, thoroughly crafted recording with great care in order to achieve a high-quality result.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="more">learn more</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--END SERVICES-->

<div class="clients">
    <div class="heading">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                    <h1>Clients</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">see more</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--END HEADING-->  

    <div class="gallery">
    <!--GALLERY START-->


        <div class="galleryinner">
            <img src="img/clients/ivey.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />

            <div class="caption">
                <div class="captionheading">
                    <h4>IVEY</h4>
                    <small>see more</small>
                </div>

                <div class="btn-group btn-trigger">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default web-link">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default web-link">More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--END CAPTION-->
        </div>
        <!--END GALLERY INNER-->

        <div class="galleryinner">
            <img src="img/clients/rufus.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />

            <div class="caption">
                <div class="captionheading">
                    <h4>RUFUS DAWKINS</h4>
                    <small>see more</small>
                </div>

                <div class="btn-group btn-trigger">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default web-link">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default web-link">More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--END CAPTION-->
        </div>
        <!--END GALLERY INNER-->

        <div class="galleryinner">
            <img src="img/clients/seddymac.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />

            <div class="caption">
                <div class="captionheading">
                    <h4>SEDDY MAC</h4>
                    <small>see more</small>
                </div>

                <div class="btn-group btn-trigger">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default web-link">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default web-link">More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--END CAPTION-->
        </div>
        <!--END GALLERY INNER-->

        <div class="galleryinner">
            <img src="img/clients/lomax.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />

            <div class="caption">
                <div class="captionheading">
                    <h4>MELISSA LOMAX</h4>
                    <small>see more</small>
                </div>

                <div class="btn-group btn-trigger">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default web-link">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default web-link">More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--END CAPTION-->
        </div>
        <!--END GALLERY INNER-->

        <div class="galleryinner">
            <img src="img/clients/jeremy.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />

            <div class="caption">
                <div class="captionheading">
                    <h4>JEREMY WILLIAMS</h4>
                    <small>see more</small>
                </div>

                <div class="btn-group btn-trigger">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default web-link">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default web-link">More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--END CAPTION-->
        </div>
        <!--END GALLERY INNER-->

        <div class="galleryinner">
            <img src="img/clients/echoing.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />

            <div class="caption">
                <div class="captionheading">
                    <h4>WHEN ALL KEPT ECHOING</h4>
                    <small>see more</small>
                </div>

                <div class="btn-group btn-trigger">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default web-link">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default web-link">More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--END CAPTION-->
        </div>
        <!--END GALLERY INNER-->

        <div class="galleryinner">
            <img src="img/clients/delisle.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />

            <div class="caption">
                <div class="captionheading">
                    <h4>RAISTLIN DELISLE</h4>
                    <small>see more</small>
                </div>

                <div class="btn-group btn-trigger">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default web-link">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default web-link">More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--END CAPTION-->
        </div>
        <!--END GALLERY INNER-->

    </div>
    <!--END GALLERY-->

</div>
<!---END CLIENTS-->

<div class="firstcontact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="email text-center">
                    <span style="font-size: 30px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope">&nbsp;</span>
                    <h5>EMAIL</h5>
                    <p>layne@contracoda.com</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="social text-center">
                    <a href="#"><span class="icon-sprite sprite-ig">&nbsp;</span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span class="icon-sprite sprite-fb">&nbsp;</span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span class="icon-sprite sprite-twitter">&nbsp;</span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span class="icon-sprite sprite-soundcloud">&nbsp;</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!---END FIRST CONTACT-->

<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <div class="copyright">
                    <small>&copy; 2017 CONTRA CODA MEDIA</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <div class="design">
                    <small>WEB DESIGN BY DISMANTLE DESIGN</small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
<!---END CLIENTS-->



<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: I couldn't understand your code clearly however it might happen for one reason are you adding your external css after the bootstrap file is included in html file?

Comment: Yes kannan is absolutely right.  A css placed in the `div` element will override a `<style></style>` while an external file will override by the `<style></style>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

On line 82 you are using a square bracket [ instead of an squiggle {, swap this and it will work:

`.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {`

This basically makes everything after the error not work, thus why your background wont change :) Also your background image will not change unless it looks the line looks like this (line 110):

`background: #363737 url(../img/tempjumbotron.jpg) no-repeat;`

Koda

Comment: That worked for the navbar issues. Do you know why my jumbotron color and background image will not appear?

Comment: The background color now is #363737 isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Well I have tried changing it to another color or adding a background image and it remains #363737. I had changed it to #363737 in the bootstrap.min.css .. I know I shouldn't have, but I was aggravated.

Comment: Nevermind, since I changed that square bracket, color works, but background image does not.

Comment: You still need to fix the bracket that I talked about in my answer. I have checked the URL and you have not yet updated style.css also your URL for the background image should be `../img/tempjumbotron.jpg`

Comment: I have fixed it. Just haven't uploaded it to the FTP.

Comment: That URL for the img worked. I swear I tried it before and it did not. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's simply because your css file is in the css folder and your image url is relative so the .. says go backwards 1 directory then go into the image folder.